# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, disabling Sticky Edges in sysSettings/Display doesn't disable sticky edges

Tags: 14.04, lts

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Since I've got two monitors, the very first thing I've tried doing was configuring them: whether I disable the sticky edges (and apply the change) or not, nothing changes in the windows and mouse pointer behaviour: the edges stay sticky, both windows and mouse pointer continue to stick to them.
Why, and how to disable that feature once and for all?